# Mockito spy failed because class member cannot be initialised

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass() {
    private MyObject myObject = getMyObject();
    public MyObject getMyObject() {
        if (myObject == null) {
            myObject = MyStaticClass.createMyObject();
        }
        return myObject;
    }
    // heaps more methods
}

public class MyTest() {
    private MyClass spyMyClass = spy(new MyClass());
    public MyTest() {
        doReturn(null).when(spyMyClass).getMyObject();
    }
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        ClassUnderTest c = new ClassUnderTest();
        assertTrue(c.someMethod(spyMyClass));
    }
}
```

The test failed with an error `Could not initialise class MyStaticClass`. The reason being this static class is initialising many more other class objects that are not available during test (e.g. database) and I do not care as you can see I am ok to return null when the method `getMyObject()` is called.

But this intention failed as well because before the `doReturn(null)` line is reached, the test has already failed at the `spy(new MyClass())` line, in which it calls `getMyObject()` to initialise the private member `myObject`.

A workaround to the above situation is to use `mock(MyClass.class)` instead of `spy(new MyClass())`, so that the private member `myObject` is not being initialised and hence not calling the real `getMyObject()` method.

But this workaround creates another headache to me because that means I will have to do some configuration (even just to `doCallRealMethod()`) for those heaps more methods within `MyClass`.

Question: is there another solution that I can still use spy on an instance of `MyClass` so that I can forget about configuring those heaps more methods within this class, yet I can get around the `Could not initialise class MyStaticClass` error?

P.S. I can't simply just use Power Mock to mock `MyStaticClass` because I am already using another test runner for `MyTest`. Unless your answer can show how easy it is to run two test runners at the same time without implementing a new hybrid test runner combining both.

---

Thanks to Adam, now I have a good working code :

```
public class MyTest() {
    private MyClass spyMyClass = spy(new MyClass() {
        @Override
        public MyObject getMyObject() {
            return null;
        }
    });
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        ClassUnderTest c = new ClassUnderTest();
        assertTrue(c.someMethod(spyMyClass));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass of `MyClass` and use it in `private MyClass spyMyClass = spy(new TestMyClass());`:

```
class TestMyClass extends MyClass {

  @Override // fortunately, the original method called in constructor can be overridden (what could be considered bad)
  public MyObject getMyObject() {
    // something that does not fail the constructor
  }

}
```

In general, this is a potential cause for problems, as you are calling a non-private, non-final method in your constructor. For the test case it might be acceptable.

Stepping away a bit, I guess it would be wise to take a look at responsibilities of this `MyClass` object. Isn't it doing too much, therefore it is hard to test and interact with? That often results in "hard-to-mock" syndrome.

Comment: Thanks, it looks a good way. Is it something standard in unit testing? `MyClass` is a util class. Not doing much but has many variants of same functions (e.g. variants of 1 or 2 or 3 parameters) so I am reluctant to mock all of them.

Comment: One could argue that multi-parameter interface bloat can increase the problem. But without seeing the source it is hard to explicitly answer. I would ask the other question - does `MyClass` do many things: e.g. give database config + give server config + give application config? If so, it could be split into three separate entities, visible only through interfaces. Then they should be easier to mock.